# How to convert vcf file to ped file using plink?

Tags: bioinformatics, vcftools, vcf-variant-call-format

I am trying to convert a .vcf file to a .ped file using plink. I have read some manuals and posts online, but it seems that no one specifically mentions how to convert vcf to ped.

I am hoping that there may be some experts here who have experience with plink to convert vcf to ped. I would appreciate it if you could share the knowledge. Moreover, if there is another way (non-plink) of doing that, please do share it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I convert my vcf files to PLINK formats (ped, fam, map) using VCFtools:
https://vcftools.github.io/man_latest.html

My commands look like this:

```
vcftools --vcf my_data.vcf --out my_data --plink
```

Comment: Usually works, however it fails with polyploid data (if they are flagged as such by e.g. freebayes variant caller).

Comment: How does `vcftools` generate the .fam / .ped files if it doesn't take pedigree info as input?

Comment: My guess is that is populates those fields with default values.

Answer (score 7):

Plink provides its own functionality for converting vcf (and other format) files to plink-compatible ones. The command you're looking for is [recode](http://zzz.bwh.harvard.edu/plink/dataman.shtml#recode) and the actual command  would look like this:

```
plink --vcf myfile.vcf.gz --recode --out myfile
```